# FreeTDS error connecting to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, freetds

I have tried all the version available from 4.2 until 7.2, it seems to me all the versions I've tried are invalid.

Looking at the errors logs and based on the [Choosing TDS protocol](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm), is SQL server 2014 supported?

Brief error:

```
Error 20017 (severity 9):
    Unexpected EOF from the server
    OS error 115, "Operation now in progress"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
```

Looking at the log dumped by tsql:

```
log.c:196:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.91
        on 2016-04-05 15:35:48 with debug flags 0x4fff.
util.c:331:tdserror(0x18ec140, 0x18ec290, 100, 0)
util.c:361:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:384:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
iconv.c:330:tds_iconv_open(0x18ec290, UTF-8)
iconv.c:187:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:187:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
iconv.c:349:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:351:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:391:preparing iconv for "ISO-8859-1" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:394:tds_iconv_open: done
net.c:205:Connecting to 192.168.1.221 port 4712 (TDS version 7.1)
net.c:270:tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
net.c:310:tds_open_socket() succeeded
util.c:156:Changed query state from DEAD to IDLE
net.c:741:Sending packet
0000 12 01 00 34 00 00 00 00-00 00 15 00 06 01 00 1b |...4.... ........|
0010 00 01 02 00 1c 00 0c 03-00 28 00 04 ff 08 00 01 |........ .(......|
0020 55 00 00 00 4d 53 53 51-4c 53 65 72 76 65 72 00 |U...MSSQ LServer.|
0030 d3 52 00 00            -                        |.R..|

net.c:555:Received header
0000 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31-                        |HTTP/1.1|

util.c:331:tdserror(0x18ec140, 0x18ec290, 20017, 115)
util.c:361:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:384:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:156:Changed query state from IDLE to DEAD
login.c:466:login packet rejected
util.c:331:tdserror(0x18ec140, 0x18ec290, 20002, 0)
util.c:361:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:384:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
mem.c:615:tds_free_all_results()
```

Comment: I'm not that sure that SQL server should return TDS header like 'HTTP/1.1' - looks like you are attempting to connect to web server [port].

Comment: @Arvo Thanks man! you pointed me to the right direction, apparently the client gave me the wrong port. Post it as the answer will you? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not that sure that SQL server should return TDS header like `HTTP/1.1` - looks like you are attempting to connect to web server (and/or wrong port).