# Unable to connect with MSSQL server using FreeTDS

Tags: php, sql-server, unix, freetds

I am trying to connect with MSSQL server but system throwing exception. Environment as below:

UNIX Server, PHP7, MSSQL,
FreeTDS version: 0.91
protocol version is 7.1/8

MSSQL Connection Issue:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server
>   connection failed (severity 9)

FreeTDS Err:

> TDS error ->server required encryption but support is not compiled in

Can anyone please help? thanks!

Comment: maybe this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421255/freetds-error-connecting-to-sql-server-2014

Answer (score 0):

The FreeTDS error message is quite clear: you are currently running a copy of FreeTDS that does not have encryption support enabled. You may have to download the FreeTDS source code and build your own copy of FreeTDS that includes encryption support.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39395549/2144390) for an example of how to do that under Ubuntu 16.04. The procedure for other *nix variants will likely be similar. Note that you will need to ensure that you have the required OpenSSL libraries available on your system so they can be compiled into FreeTDS.